# Setting UINavigationBar appearance ignored in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to set the UINavigationBar appearance (`tintColor`, `barTintColor` etc) between screens, but at the moment in iOS 11 most of this seems to be completely ignored or doesn't behave as expected. The bar appearance changes inside a single navigation controller, when a view is pushed or popped. I have two functions, which I call in `viewWillAppear`.

I need to be able to set the title colour, the left and right bar button item colour, back button colour and bar tint colour.

I'm trying to get just the colours working at the moment, so I tried this, but no joy.

```
public func setDarkHeaderStyle() {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colours.secondaryNavy
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
}

public func setLightHeaderStyle() {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default

    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = Colours.primaryNavy
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
}
```

[image: Dark style]
[image: Light style]

If I instead use the navigation controller to set the colours, it does work for the bar tint, the `UIBarButtonItem` and the back button, but the title is incorrect.

```
public func setDarkHeaderStyle() {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Colours.secondaryNavy
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}

public func setLightHeaderStyle() {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Colours.primaryNavy
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

[image: Dark style]
[image: Light style]

So I manually set the title text attributes with the following:

```
public func setDarkHeaderStyle() {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: Fonts.fontRegularName, size: 16)!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.kern: 0.2,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white
    ]

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Colours.secondaryNavy
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}

public func setLightHeaderStyle() {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default

    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: Fonts.fontRegularName, size: 16)!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.kern: 0.2,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: Colours.primaryNavy
    ]

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = Colours.primaryNavy
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

This seems to work, *except* when you pop back to the root view the title colour isn't set:

[image: Dark initial load]
[image: Light initial load]
[image: Dark popped]

I guess I have two questions:

Why doesn't `UINavigationBar.appearance()` work?
How can I get this working reliably?

Comment: why don't you use the [`preferredStatusBarStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621416-preferredstatusbarstyle) in the view-contoller instead, and set the navigation bar's appearance in the `viewWillAppear(_:)` method, for instance?

Comment: Well the status bar style is working fine... it's the title of the `UINavigationBar` that isn't working, which I am setting in `viewWillAppear`. Each of these functions is called in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug. `UIBarNavigationItem` for some reason seems to ignore your changes on its title attributes and tint color unless the text of your title changes. This is a weird behaviour and you might consider reporting it. A workaround could be to toggle an empty space suffix to your title:

```
// Hack!!! adds and removes an empty space to the title to 
// force the bar item reset title attributes.
let title: String = barItem.title ?? ""
barItem.title = title.hasSuffix(" ") ? String(title.dropLast()) : title + " "
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work :(. In fact, it works if I set the styles (with this workaround) in `viewDidAppear` as well as `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: You should call it only once, I use this code to toggle the colors on button action over and over again. You need to make sure nothing else sets the titles back.

Answer (score 0):

I try something that works on my UIViewController (both global & current navigation bar appearance):

```
        UINavigationBarAppearance* appearance = [[UINavigationBarAppearance alloc] init];
        appearance.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        appearance.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};

        [UINavigationBar appearance].standardAppearance = appearance;
        [UINavigationBar appearance].scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance;
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance;
```